Excel file with VBA open tooo slow when upload to the Sharepoint
I am currently interning at the company and need to develop a VBA for supplier consolidation. There are two main files: one for company departments to input vendor information and another for management to view vendor details. Both files contain VBA and link to each other. I have uploaded 12+ files to SharePoint and shared them with several colleagues, but some are experiencing very slow opening times when open the file(maybe 1 or 2 mins). Is there a way to improve the opening speed, or is there a better platform for sharing?(PS: the files size are not very big, sometimes have error messages like discard change or OLE action...)
I've tried to fix the issues, such as discarding changes or OLE operations, or swapping files to OneDrive, but since it's shared to so many people, I can't change the Excel settings for each user. I'm not even sure why I'm having so many issues after uploading to SharePoint.

How big are these files? Can you tell us how slow "tooo slow" is, preferably using a time measure? are we talking seconds or minutes here and how many?

There are 45 files in SharePoint, each ranging from approximately 30 to 100MB. The time it takes to open these files is inconsistent—sometimes they open quickly, but other times it takes up to a minute. Occasionally, error messages like "OLE action" or other errors pop up, but they typically resolve after closing and reopening the file.
